# Max of two columns conditional to a given constant

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, max, conditional-statements

I have a pandas DF with several columns. I want to apply the following (conceptual):

`df['Z'] = int( max(df[['A','B']].max(axis=1) ) > CONST )`

In other words:

1) `max(df[['A','B']]) > CONST` would return `TRUE` or `FALSE`

2) in `df['Z']` I want to store a `1` or `0`, depending on the previous condition.

I know that to get the max of two columns I can do:

```
df['Z'] = df[['A','B']].max(axis=1)
```

I don't know how to compare that max with a given CONST?

How can I accomplish that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost there. Consider this dummy df,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [5,9,3,17,52], 'B': [94,23,5,12,2]})
```

for a constant

```
const = 20
df['Z'] = (df[['A','B']].max(axis=1) > const).astype(int)
```

You get

```
    A   B   Z
0   5   94  1
1   9   23  1
2   3   5   0
3   17  12  0
4   52  2   1
```

Comment: ja! it was almost there, indeed! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

```
df[[‘A’, ‘B’]].gt(const).any(1).astype(int)
```